# How to calculate distances between rows in dataframe and create a matrix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
sample = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['1','0','1','0'],'Col2':['0','0','1','1'],'Col3':['0','0','1','0'],'Class':['A','B','A','B']},index=['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4'])
In [32]: print(sample)
Out [32]:
      Col1 Col2 Col3 Class
Item1    1    0    0    A
Item2    0    0    0    B
Item3    1    1    1    A
Item4    0    1    0    B
```

And I want to calculate row distances between differents class' rows. I mean, first of all I would like to calculate distance between rows from classA

```
       Item1   Item3
Item1  0       0.67
Item3 0.67     0
```

Secondly, distances between rows from class B

```
       Item2   Item4
Item2  0       1
Item4  1       0
```

And lastly distance between different classes.

```
       Item2   Item4
Item1  1       1
Item3  1       0.67
```

I have tried calculating distances with DistanceMetric one by one

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('jacquard')
```

But I don't know can I do it iterating over the different rows in a large dataframe and create this 3 different matrix wth the distances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find distances within Class A and Class B, you can use `DataFrame.groupby`, (distance used is `euclidean`):

```
def find_distance(group):
    return pd.DataFrame(dist.pairwise(group.values))

df.groupby('Class').apply(find_distance)

            0           1
Class           
A      0    0.000000    1.414214
       1    1.414214    0.000000
B      0    0.000000    1.000000
       1    1.000000    0.000000
```

If you only have two classes, you can separate the two classes into two dataframes and then calculate the difference:

```
dist_cols = ['Col1', 'Col2','Col3']
df_a = df[df['Class']=='A']
df_b = df[df['Class']=='B']

distances = dist.pairwise(df_a[dist_cols].values, df_b[dist_cols].values)
distances
> array([[1.        , 1.41421356],
       [1.73205081, 1.41421356]])

pd.DataFrame(distances, columns = df_b.index, index = df_a.index)

          Item2       Item4
Item1   1.000000    1.414214
Item3   1.732051    1.414214
```

Comment: 0, 1  -> what is it?

Comment: The corresponding Items

Comment: Thanks,It works perfectly calculating distances within classes but  I have tried to execute the same command without ```groupby``` to calculate distances between different classes and It did't work :( What can I do?

Comment: Do you only have two classes? or could there be more than 2?

Comment: I only have 2 classes

Comment: Hey @NellyLouis, I have edited my answer. Let me know if it works for you :)